# Canonical Markov Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $X$ be a canonical, right-continuous Markov process with values in a Polish state space $E$, equipped with Borel-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{E}$ and we assume that $t\rightarrow E_{X_{t}}f(X_{s})$ is right continuous everywhere for each bounded continuous function f.

For $x\in E$ define $\sigma_{x}=\inf\{t>0\mid X_{t}\neq x\}$.

I've come to the conclusion that $\sigma_{x}$ is an optional time. I would now like to use the Markov property of $X$ to show that for every $x\in E$ it holds that

$$P_{x}\{\sigma_{x}>t+s\}=P_{x}\{\sigma_{x}>t\}P_{x}\{\sigma_{x}>s\}$$
for all $s,t\geq 0$

I've tried using the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{\sigma_{x}>t+s}$ but didnt come to the desired result. Could anyone help me prove this?

Comment: I think the multiplicative property is not true (this is known as the memoryless property). That would imply that any hitting time is an exponential random variable. I think this is too strong to be true.

Try to rephrase your question

Comment: @Bunder Read the question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed $\sigma_x$ is exponentially distributed under $P_x$. To see this, note that $[\sigma_x\gt s]\subseteq[X_s=x]$ hence 
$$
P_x[\sigma_x\gt t+s\mid\sigma_x\gt s]=P_x[\sigma_x\gt t+s\mid X_s=x]=P_x[\sigma_x\gt t].
$$
This is specific to the starting distribution $P_x$. For other starting distributions, the distribution of $\sigma_x$ is the barycenter of the exponential distribution $P_x\circ\sigma_x^{-1}$ and of the Dirac mass at $0$ with respective weights $P[X_0=x]$ and $1-P[X_0=x]$.

Comment: I think the weights are inverted. 
Why this is not true for the BM? I mean, for a standard BM $\sigma_a$ with $a > 0$ has the following density $$ \frac{a}{\sqrt{2 \pi t^3}} \exp{-\frac{a^2}{2t}}$$ for $t > 0$

Comment: Not at all. You are confusing the first hitting time of $a\ne0$ by the process starting at $0$ (your comment) with the exit time of $x$ by the process starting at $x$ (your question). // The exit time of $0$ by the Brownian motion starting at $0$ is $0$ almost surely.

Comment: Now I got it, indeed I was confused. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your response, my problem however is seeing how it follows from the Markov property as I'm trying to prove the exponential distribution of $\sigma_{x}$.

Comment: Markov property justifies the first $=$ sign in the answer.

Comment: Could you help me see how $$\mathbb{E}_{x}(f(X_{t+s})\mid\mathcal{F}_{s})=\mathbb{E}_{X_{s}}f(X_{t})$$ translates into that?

Comment: $P_x[\sigma_x\gt t+s\mid\sigma_x\gt s]=P_x[\sigma_x\gt t+s\mid\sigma_x\gt s, X_s=x]=P_{x}[\sigma_x\gt t]$.

Comment: No sorry... what function $f$ did you use? Must be an indicator function to get the probability, and one can only plug $X_{t+s}$ into $f$ not the optional time.

Comment: Markov property is not only the fact that for every $f$, $E_x(f(X_{t+s})\mid\mathcal F_s)=E_{X_s}(f(X_t))$ but rather the property that for every functional $\Phi$, $E_x(\Phi((X_{u+s})_{u\geqslant0})\mid\mathcal F_s)=E_{X_s}(\Phi((X_u)_{u\geqslant0}))$. One applies this to $\Phi((X_u)_{u\geqslant0})=\mathbf 1_A$ with $A=[\sigma_x\gt t]=[\forall u\leqslant t,X_u\ne x]$.